# insert default value of a table into another table

Tags: php, postgresql

Simplified version:

I have a table named books (book_id, book_title) where book_id is the primary key and of type serial (so it is assigned automatically without me inserting it).

I also have another table named book_version (id, book_id, book_version) where book_id is foreign key to the first table.

With a form I take the book title and version. I insert the title into the first table and have to insert the generated book_id along with version into the second table.

How can I do that without having 3 separate queries (one insert for first table, one select to get it's id and one insert for the second table)?

The idea here is that the same book may have been published several times with slight changes, so i want to keep track of different versions.

Comment: I think this is a problem you can only solve using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: Your question would be more understandable if you post the create statements of the tables as well as the SQLs in addition to your prose description.

Comment: insert into first table, get last insert id, and insert this id as a forign key for second table with second table data

Comment: @devpro In the question I mentioned that I would rather not do it like this. Three queries are what I am trying to avoid :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an after insert trigger on the first table:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

An after insert trigger can reference the inserted row and then  you only have to run 1 statement to insert the version.

You only have to insert the first row via PHP, and your trigger is installed in the database and does the work after that.

That is the best way to do it, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a stored procedure and delegate the work to it. There will still be 3 queries, but those 3 queries will be executed in MySQL. Your PHP code would only see it as 1 query,

Answer (score 1):

```
 mysql_insert_id() is mysql function which gets last inserted id into database.

<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db('mydb');

here book_id is autofill 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO books ('book_title') values ('kossu')");
```

$last_insert_id = mysql_insert_id();

Now for second table id is autofill

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO book_version ('book_id', 'book_version') values ($last_insert_id,'6.48' )");
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Although there were some pretty good ideas here (ie. triggers, stored procedures or getting last inserted row) , using the **Returning** functionality seemed like the best solution, at least in my case.